# Make RPM Ansible fails with Python error

Tags: pip, yum, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to install Ansible on a machine with RHEL 7.2 in order to create an Ansible Server.

I need Ansible v2.4 or newer and for this I've performed the following steps:

```
 1. yum -y install git asciidoc rpm-build python2-devel
 2. cd /usr/src
 3. git clone git://github.com/ansible/ansible.git --recursive
 4. cd ansible
 5. git checkout stable-2.4
```

Since now everything worked fine, but now I want to run this command:

`make rpm` and after that: `yum install rpm-build/ansible-2.4-0.git201601051704.a2a786e.stable201.el7.centos.noarch.rpm`

But when I'm running `make rpm`, I received the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "packaging/release/versionhelper/version_helper.py", line 9, in <module>
    from packaging.version import Version, VERSION_PATTERN
ImportError: No module named packaging.version
Makefile:39: *** "version_helper failed".  Stop.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've just found the solution for my problem:

run `pip install packaging`

Comment: Hours of looking at folks that said various things boiling down to "re-install PIP".  And it was just that there was a missing, undocumented dependency.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this error on CentOS 7

First you need to install pip by running:

```
yum -y install python-pip
```

Then to clear the errors, run:

```
pip install packaging
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of rhel7 follow below steps:

- install pip using python

  wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
  python get-pip.py
- install pythonpip

  yum install -y python-pip
- install packaging

  pip install packaging